# JNI: No rule to make target issue

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, java-native-interface, libgdx

I am just getting into JNI in Eclipse and have followed the Eclipse part of [this](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html#zz-2.4) JNI tutorial in Ubuntu. I manage to get that working by using the following folder structure:

```
.
└── HelloJNI
    ├── bin
    │   └── HelloJNI.class
    ├── jni
    │   ├── HelloJNI.c
    │   ├── HelloJNI.h
    │   ├── HelloJNI.o
    │   ├── libhello.so
    │   └── makefile
    └── src
        ├── HelloJNI.class
        └── HelloJNI.java
```

My makefile in this project looks like this:

```
# Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : libhello.so

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
libhello.so : HelloJNI.o
    gcc -shared -fpic -o $@ $<

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
HelloJNI.o : HelloJNI.c HelloJNI.h
    gcc -fpic -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include/linux" -c $< -o $@

# $* matches the target filename without the extension
HelloJNI.h : HelloJNI.class
javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*

clean :
    rm HelloJNI.h HelloJNI.o libhello.so
```

Now I want to replicate this in my Libgdx project for Android. My folder structure for the core project here looks like this:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── com
│   │   └── test
│   │       └── mytestgame
│   │           ├── TestGame.class
│   │           └── TextGenerator.class
│   └── TestGame.gwt.xml
├── jni
│   └── makefile
├── libs
│   ├── gdx.jar
│   └── gdx-sources.jar
└── src
    ├── com
    │   └── test
    │       └── mytestgame
    │           ├── TestGame.java
    │           └── TextGenerator.java
    └── TestGame.gwt.xml
```

And my makefile in this project is defined as:

```
# Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : libTextGenerator.so

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
libTextGenerator.so : TextGenerator.o
        gcc -shared -fpic -o $@ $<

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
TextGenerator.o : TextGenerator.cpp TextGenerator.h
        gcc -fpic -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-    openjdk-amd64/include/linux" -c $< -o $@

# $* matches the target filename without the extension
TextGenerator.h : TextGenerator.class
        javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*

clean :
        rm TextGenerator.h TextGenerator.o libTextGenerator.so
```

The `TextGenerator` class will only work as a small class producing a semi-random text to test that I can use a String from C++ in Java. This class looks like this:

```
package com.test.mytestgame;

public class TextGenerator {
    static{
            System.load("TextGenerator"); // Filename libTextGenerator.so
    }

    /**Empty constructor.*/
    public TextGenerator(){
    }

    /**Returns a semi-not-so-random-text*/
    public native String generateText();    
}
```

The problem now is that when I try to run the `TextGenerator.h` part of the makefile, I get the following error:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project my-fluids-game ****

make TextGenerator.h 
make: *** No rule to make target `TextGenerator.class', needed by `TextGenerator.h'.  Stop.

**** Build Finished ****
```

I have tried changing the `CLASS_PATH` variable to `../bin/com/test/mytestgame` but this does only produce other errors. As far as I have understood, it is ok to use ../bin when using the `-classpath` flag.

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong here? I guess this is a relatively small detail, but my understanding of this is currently limited.

Comment: Why is the [**android**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag mentioned here?

Comment: You are right - this has nothing to do with Android. Tag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` does not know about classpath.

The rule should be

```
TextGenerator.h : ../bin/com/test/mytestgame/TextGenerator.class
    javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $(<F)
```

*But I really don't know how you are going to use the javah-generated include file.*

Comment: Do you mean `../bin/com/test/mytestgame/TextGenerator.class`, that is with the `../` first? When not using `../` I get `No rule to make target` again. If I include the `../` I get the error `Error: No classes were specified on the command line.  Try -help.
make: *** [TextGenerator.h] Error 15`. If I also change the `$(CLASS_PATH)` part to the above either with or without `../` I get other errors. The javah generated header file will be used to create a cpp file to just return a String. This is just the beginning for me to start using JNI. I have also made sure that `TextGenerator.class` exists

Comment: If you run **make** from the `jni` directory then yes,  you need `../`

Comment: You need `javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $(<F)`, answer fixed

Comment: I cannot make it work, neither by running `make` in the `jni` folder nor by running `Make target` on `TextGenerator.h` in Eclipse directly. I notice one other thing, however; in the first mentioned project I can go to the folder of `HelloJNI.class` and do `javah HelloJNI` to create the header file. This does not work in the current project. If I go to bin/com/test/mytestgame and do `javah TextGenerator` I get the error message `error: cannot access TextGenerator bad class file: RegularFileObject[./TextGenerator.class]
class file contains wrong class: com.test.mytestgame.TextGenerator`.

Comment: Ok, so I changed to `javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) com.test.mytestgame.TextGenerator` and it works. Thanks for helping me in the right direction! :)